# Safari is sluggish and many websites produce a message about using significant memory

Tags: macos, safari, websites

I'm running High Sierra on my older iMac with 16 GB of ram. I use Safari and I often have 5 or 6 websites open at once. Throughout the day I will very often encounter a website that will produce the following message at the top of the webpage:

> This webpage is using significant memory. Closing it may improve the
>   responsiveness of your Mac.

This happens a lot and Safari becomes sluggish on all the other webpages as well. This happens to sites I want to use so closing the webpage is not the best option.

I haven't noticed this in the Chrome Browser but I haven't used that browser very often and would like to continue using Safari. What is causing this to happen and is there a way to stop it?

Comment: I also use High Sierra, and frequently experience that on my mid-2014 MacBook Pro.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that.  You know how frustrating this can be!

Comment: Have you isolated any extension? Does this happen in safe boot ? And lastly, try “emptying cache” and deleting cookies and website data. Not history though.. that’d be bizarre